# Eclipse Android builds vs Ant Android Buiilds

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

When I right click on a project on Eclipse and click on "Run as Android App", does it have a different build process then Ant builds?

Currently I am working on an app that uses another project as a library dependence.  Everything compiles fine and the app loads, but when I try to use the functionality the library provides, problems come up.  The library has a checksum file to verify that the library resources are loaded correctly.  When I build to my phone from Eclipse, this check passes.  But when I use my ant build, the resource check fails.

I have compared both apk results (diff -rq ant/ eclipse/) and my differences are as follows:

```
Files ant/AndroidManifest.xml and eclipse/AndroidManifest.xml differ  (this is  expected)
Files ant/META-INF/CERT.RSA and eclipse/META-INF/CERT.RSA differ
Files ant/META-INF/CERT.SF and eclipse/META-INF/CERT.SF differ
Files ant/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and eclipse/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF differ
Files ant/classes.dex and eclipse/classes.dex differ
Files ant/resources.arsc and eclipse/resources.arsc differ
```

I  suspect resources.arsc may be causing the problem.  The size of these files are only 8 bytes different.

I'm lost on this, anyone have an idea of why this is happening.  I've tried deleting the checksum file, but the library won't work without it.

Comment: I suggest you switch to IntelliJ, and use Maven.

Comment: I'm unable to do this as it is company software, I am forced to use what I'm using right now.  Plus I have a deadline soon and am unable to do such a change.

Comment: The company shouldn't be dictating which IDE you are using to do your work.